# Get closest element with given id using javascript

Tags: javascript, onclick

I need to add a class to the closest div with a given id after I click the div above it. My example below should make more sense of what I need.

```
<style>
.menuContent {display:none;}
.expandMenu {display:inherit;}
</style>

<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="menuIcon" onclick="expandMenu('menuContent');">+</div>
    <div id="menuContent" class="menuContent">
        <p>This</p>
        <p>That</p>
        <p>The Other</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="menuIcon" onclick="expandMenu('menuContent');">+</div>
    <div id="menuContent" class="menuContent">
        <p>This</p>
        <p>That</p>
        <p>The Other</p>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

This is the script I have so far that searches the class names of the given element and adds or removes the 'expandMenu' class when clicked.

```
<script>
function expandMenu(x) {
    var d = document.getElementById(x);
    var c = d.className;
    if (c.search("expandMenu") === -1) {
        d.className += " expandMenu";   
    } else {
        d.className = c.replace(" expandMenu","");
    }
}
</script>
```

This is all working fine, the issue is when clicking the 'menuIcon' in the second 'li', it's the first 'li' element that the script is applied too - it's obviously just finding the first 'menuContent' and applying the className function to it.

How can I limit the function to only apply to the 'menuContent' div that is directly after it.

I don't want to use jQuery either - good ol' fashioned plain Javascript would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give the menu icons unique ids, and pass that id to the function. Toggle based on the id, instead of the class. You are right, it is choosing the first one because it has found it when running through the code.

Comment: Thanks - that's one method I have used to achieve this - but I would prefer not to add a unique ID for each element if I can. Just makes it a little messy.

Comment: Messy? if anything, that is correct organization. Instead you can say that you want the "nth child". jQuery has a selector that you can use, so if you want to include query, that will help. ID's, however, are meant to make organization cleaner and unique, so I don't know why you think it is messy.

Comment: Yeah I do understand what you are saying - and it's exactly the method that I am currently using - and it's working perfectly. I just didn't like the fact that every id was different (which I know is exactly what they are supposed to be). Appreciate your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should not have the same `id` on multiple elements. Try changing one of the `id`'s and passing the new id to the function.

```
<style>
.menuContent {display:none;}
.expandMenu {display:inherit;}
</style>

<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="menuIcon" onclick="expandMenu('menuContent1');">+</div>
    <div id="menuContent1" class="menuContent">
        <p>This</p>
        <p>That</p>
        <p>The Other</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="menuIcon" onclick="expandMenu('menuContent2');">+</div>
    <div id="menuContent2" class="menuContent">
        <p>This</p>
        <p>That</p>
        <p>The Other</p>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks - although that will solve the problem - I feel like there must be a more standard way of doing what I'm after. Or is this the standard way?

Comment: You could get the parent of the `div` that was clicked if you bind this function to the onClick event for the element with class `menuContent`. This passes an event to the function which includes the clicked element then use that to find the child element with the `menuContent` class. Then you can add or remove the `expandMenu` class.